# Java immutability when defining members in a function called by constructor

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, immutability

I have class like this:

```
abstract class Parent {
  protected Parent(Raw rawData) {
     deserialize(rawData);
  }
  protected abstract void deserialize(Raw rawData);
}

class Child extends Parent {
   final byte firstByte;
   public Child(Raw rawdData) { super(rawData); }
   protected void deserialize(Raw rawData) { 
     firstByte = rawData.getFirst();
   }
}
```

So basically any child class that extends Parent will define a `deserialize()` to deserialize the rawData to fill in their member variables, and in their constructor they will just do `super(rawData)`. The `deserialize` function of the child class will automatically execute.

Error message:

```
Child.java:5: error: cannot assign a value to final variable firstByte
 firstByte = rawData.getFirst();
```

However doing this Java does not allow me to define member variables as `final` which is weird because I'm doing initialization in the constructor. What is the best way to do the same functionality but allowing member to be `final` ?

Comment: What member variable? Can you give the example *with* said member variable and the compilation error that you get?

Comment: Added the child class, the error is basically I can't define member `firstByte` as final

Comment: You don't really need the final modifier to make a class immutable. Encapsulation can do that.

Comment: @NickJ you mean I should maintain another class to keep all the deserialized data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A final variable can be assigned a value only once. The compiler doesn't check whether a method is called only once; hence, final variables cannot be assigned in methods. (In case of the `deserialize` method the compiler couldn't determine if the method is called only once, even if it would want to. The method is protected and there is nothing which prevents a subclass from calling it twice.) Thus, you can only assign to final member variables in the constructor (or initialize them immediately when you define them).

The solution is to make the variable not final. You can still ensure that instances of your class are immutable by restricting access to the variable (make it private) and only provide a getter for it (if you needs its value outside of the class).

Note also that it is better not to call methods from a constructor, especially methods which can be overridden by subclasses. Although it will probably work now if you not depend on the state of the object, you have to realize that when the method is called, the object is not completely constructed yet. If you (or someone else) want to modify that method in the future, you may have forgotten this and introduce hard-to-find bugs. For example, the following little program:

```
class Bar {
    public Bar() {
        f();
    }    
    protected void f() { }
}

public class Foo extends Bar  {
    final String a;
    public Foo() {
        a = "Hello";
    }
    protected void f() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.a);
    }
}
```

outputs

```
null
Hello
```

although the same final string reference is printed two times.

So yes, you should call your `deserialize` method in each of the subclasses' constructor instead of in the superclass constructor, so that each constructor only constructs the part of the object it knows about.

Answer (score 4):

When you call a super constructor, the "super" part of the object is being constructed, while the "sub" part of the object is a complete waste land; you may not read from or write ot it; actually the "sub" part may not even exist conceptually.

A super constructor calling an abstract method is a very bad idea, because it may depend on the subclass state, which does not exist yet.

Comment: a related discussion - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/8kaBhp4Uzq4

Comment: So if I want to have the same functionality, i.e. each subclass must define a deserializer and eventually deserialize the rawData, what is the Java-ist way?

Comment: instead of `abstract` class and method, subclass can supply a functional object to the super constructor, which is invoked there; this functional object won't be able to depend on the subclass state.

Comment: I don't get the "functional object" could you give a short code snippet or point me a link ?

Comment: e.g. `Parent(Raw rawData, Function<RawData,Object> deserializer)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as the compilation error, you can't delegate the assignment of the `final` to another method.  You *must* do the assignment in the constructor or inline with the declaration.

```
    public Child(Raw rawdData) { 
        super(rawData);
        firstByte = rawData.getFirst();
    }
```

As bayou.io states, calling an abstract method from a constructor is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: I want to enforce each subclass having a deserializer, any suggestion ?

Comment: Using an abstract method is fine to enforce that, but it shouldn't be called from a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are calling deserialize from the constructor.  You cannot really enforce that deserialize is only called from the constructor.

The java compiler knows this, and this is why it's complaining.   Final member variables can only be assigned at initialization or within the constructor.

Hope this helps.